# How to pass c++ function/lambda as none-type parameter to a typedef/using template?

Tags: c++, function, templates, shared-ptr, using

I've got a need to write RAII wrapper functions/classes to some C library. I know we can use a smart pointer and pass a `deleter` function, like this:

```
FILE* pf = fopen("NoSuchFile", "r");
shared_ptr<FILE> p1{pf, fclose}; // OK.
```

But, for more complex scenarios other than `fopen()`/`fclose()`, I don't wish to write code to pass `deleter` functions each time I declare such a wrapper. Especially if we decide to update/replace the `deleter` function, a lot of code has to be changed.

What I wish to have, is something like this (to make code cleaner):

```
template<typename T, fn ???? > // how to specify this "fn" parameter?
using sp_with_deleter = shared_ptr<T, fn>;
```

Then in client code, I can do this:

```
using smartFp = sp_with_deleter<FILE*, fclose>;
...
FILE* f1 = fopen(xxx);
FILE* f2 = fopen(yyy);
smartFp sf1(f1); // no need to pass deleter function.
smartFp sf2(f2);
...
```

Is there a way to achieve this `sp_with_deleter` type?

Comment: Why not create a `make_sp_with()` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you propose will NOT work for `std::shared_ptr`, simply because the `deleter` is not a template parameter of `std::shared_ptr`. So, you can't specify a `deleter` in a `typedef`/`using` statement when aliasing a `std::shared_ptr` type. It can only be specified in the `std:::shared_ptr`'s constructor.

If you don't want to specify a `deleter` on every `std::shared_ptr` variable declaration, then you will need to write a wrapper function instead, eg:

```
auto make_smartFp(FILE* f) {
    return std::shared_ptr<FILE>{f, &fclose};

    // alternatively:
    auto deleter = [](FILE* f){ fclose(f); };
    return std::shared_ptr<FILE>{f, deleter};
}

...
auto sf1 = make_smartFp(fopen(xxx)); // no need to pass deleter function.
auto sf2 = make_smartFp(fopen(yyy));
...
```

You can do something similar for `std::unique_ptr`, too. Even though the *type* of the `deleter` is a template argument, when using a function or lambda as the `deleter` then the *actual* `deleter` must be passed in the constructor, eg:

```
auto make_smartFp(FILE* f) {
    return std::unique_ptr<FILE, decltype(&fclose)>{f, &fclose};

    // alternatively:
    auto deleter = [](FILE *f){ fclose(f); };
    return std::unique_ptr<FILE, decltype(deleter)>{t, deleter};
}

...
smartFp sf1(fopen(xxx)); // no need to pass deleter function.
smartFp sf2(fopen(yyy));
...
```

Otherwise, you can instead make the `deleter` be a default-constructable class type, then you don't need to pass it in a parameter to `std::unique_ptr`'s constructor, eg:

```
struct FILE_deleter {
    void operator()(FILE *f) { fclose(f); }
};
using smartFp = std::unique_ptr<FILE, FILE_deleter>;

...
smartFp sf1(fopen(xxx)); // no need to pass deleter function.
smartFp sf2(fopen(yyy));
...
```